# Как прочитать данные ярлыка через python

Tags: python, windows

есть ли способ прочесть путь к которому ведёт ярлык?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy можно оформить как ответ на ruSO и в комментариях оставить "ассоциация <ссылка на ответ на enSO>"

Comment: Спасибо, оба способа помогли!

Comment: @Dmitry понял, спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys
import win32com.client 

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("t:\\test.lnk")
print(shortcut.Targetpath)
```

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/a/571573/10562663

Comment: Из коробки нет `win32com`, его ставят через `pip install pywin32`. И `import sys` тут ненужен :)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант через [winshell](https://github.com/tjguk/winshell) ([документация](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortcuts.html)):

```
# pip install winshell
import winshell

shortcut = winshell.shortcut(<путь до ярлыка>)
print(shortcut.path)
```